# How do I add an ID to each day in a calendar with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, local-storage

How would I add an ID to each day with the following code? I thought I could just use `days.id` but this doesn't seem to work. I want each calendar day to have an ID so I can get events from local storage.

```
for (i = 1; i<= lastDay; i++ ){
    days += `<div>${i}</div>`;
  
}
```

I have tried days.id Math.random(1,100) but this is not working.
Here is the full javascript code

```
const date = new Date();

const renderCalendar = () =>{

    const monthDays = document.querySelector('.days');

    const calendar = document.querySelector('.calendar')

    let lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() +1, 0).getDate();
    
    let prevLastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0).getDate();
    
    const firstDayIndex = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).getDay();
    
    const lastDayIndex = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDay();
    
    const months = [
        'January', 
        'February',
        'March', 
        'April', 
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November', 
        'December'
    ]
    
    document.querySelector('.date h1').innerHTML = months[date.getMonth()];
    document.querySelector('.date p').innerHTML = date.toDateString();
    
    let days = '';
    for (x = firstDayIndex; x > 0; x--){
        days += `<div class="prev-date">${prevLastDay - x +1}</div>`
        
    }
    
    for (i = 1; i<= lastDay; i++ ){
        days += `<div>${i}</div>`;
      
    }
    
    for (j = 1; j< 7 - lastDayIndex; j++){
          days += `<div>${j}</div>`;          
    }

    monthDays.innerHTML = days


}

document.querySelector('.calendar').addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML)
})

document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', () =>{
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() -1)
    renderCalendar();
})
document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', () =>{
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() +1)
    renderCalendar();
})
renderCalendar();
```

Comment: What is `days`?

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? What didn't work? We only know about the details you provide.

Comment: days is each day of the month. 1-28 for this month. I just posted the full javascript code

Comment: I thought I could place days.id in the for loop under    for (i = 1; i<= lastDay; i++ ){
        days += `<div>${i}</div>`;
      
    } then I tried to console.log the IDs but it comes back as undefined

Comment: `<div id="${your id here}">${i}</div>`